# XSL datetime, remove and condense timezone into time

Tags: datetime, xslt, timezone, xslt-2.0

I'm saving some timestamps in my XML results in standard UTC format.

What I'd like to be able to do is re-convert this to human readable times.  Without the timezone addendum.  As far as I've been able to get so far is:

```
format-dateTime(
  xs:dateTime(
   adjust-dateTime-to-timezone(
      xs:dateTime(@thevalue),xs:dayTimeDuration('P0DT4H')
   )
  ),'[M01]/[D01]/[Y0001]  [H01]:[m01]:[s01]'
)
```

where @thevalue is like: `2006-02-15T17:00:00`

It's giving me a headache because the formatter returns a time of 17:00.  If I peel back a layer of the format-dateTime to see what the adjust-dateTime function returns, it gives

`2006-02-15T17:00:00+04:00`

... and all I really want to see is 21:00...  so very frustrated.  Anyone deal with this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here is a transformation that does what you want**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vDateTime" as="xs:dateTime"
  select="xs:dateTime('2006-02-15T17:00:00+00:00')"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:sequence select=
   "adjust-dateTime-to-timezone($vDateTime,
                                xs:dayTimeDuration('P0DT4H')
                               )"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied to any XML document (not used), the result is**:

```
2006-02-15T21:00:00+04:00
```

**And the complete solution is:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vDateTime" as="xs:dateTime"
  select="xs:dateTime('2006-02-15T17:00:00+00:00')"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:variable name="vadjustedDateTime" select=
   "adjust-dateTime-to-timezone($vDateTime,
                                xs:dayTimeDuration('P0DT4H')
                               )"/>

  <xsl:sequence select=
  "format-dateTime($vadjustedDateTime,
                   '[M01]/[D01]/[Y0001]  [H01]:[m01]:[s01]'
                   )
  "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**which produces this result**:

```
02/15/2006  21:00:00
```

Comment: Your comment helped me greatly understand my problem.  I can't modify the format in which i save my dates (UTC, but without the +HHMM notation) but I was able to hack it together by transforming it to a +00:00, then applying +04:00, then adjust-dateTime-to-timezone, and then format.  Thanks!